# Rotating a element defined in css pseudo class

Tags: css

I got element which is used after some pseudo class, it's working fine, until when i want it to flip upside down and add a tranform effect, it fails. The end result is the whole li transforming.

```
    .dropdown-menu li a:first-child:nth-last-child(2):after {
      content: '';
      background-color: #fff;
      background:url('../img/open.png') no-repeat;
      width: 18px;
      height: 10px;
      display:inline-block;
      margin:-15px 0 0 35px;
      float: right;

}
.dropdown-menu li a:hover{
        -ms-transform: rotate(180deg); /* IE 9 */
        -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg); /* Safari */
        transform: rotate(180deg);
        }
```

Also is it worth doing it in css or jquery, as css3 support might be limited?

Comment: You mean the `:after` element is also rotating but you don't want it to? If yes, you need apply reverse rotation on the `:after` while hovering on. It will otherwise get transformed because `:after` elements are children of the element to which it is attached.

Comment: @Harry i just want the :after element to rotate, not the whole li element.

Comment: If that's the case then you can directly apply the `transform` on the `:after` element. If it still doesn't work, please create a demo and add it to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it with little help of @harry and it works. I was targeting wrong child. correct code is

```
    .dropdown-menu li a:first-child:nth-last-child(2):after {
      content: '';
      background-color: #fff;
      background:url('../img/open.png') no-repeat;
      width: 18px;
      height: 10px;
      display:inline-block;
      margin:-15px 0 0 35px;
      float: right;

}
.dropdown-menu li a:hover:after{
    -ms-transform: rotate(18deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg); /* Safari */
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: linear; /* Safari and Chrome */
    transition-timing-function: linear;
        }
```